# Allow not calendar dates in lubridate

Tags: r, date

I'm using the lubridate library to deal with time series data, the problem I have is that the dates I have do not match with calendar dates, but are referenced to the time where the experiment started.

For that that reason, dates as:

```
ymd_hms("2017-02-30-20-10-6")
```

For which I get the following warning:

```
 1 failed to parse.
```

In consequence, the string is not parsed as a date,  since February does not have that many days, is there an alternative to handle this cases with the library?

The output I would like to have for that date is:

```
2017-02-30 20:10:16
```

Comment: @akrun I just updated the question

Comment: you may need to keep as character itself as there is no Date with that

Comment: If formatting is the issue `sub("^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-", "\\1 \\2:\\3:", "2017-02-30-20-10-6")` can correct, but if you are tryingn to convert Datetime class, it wouldn't work because that date doesn't exist